# Vitali like set construction for a general family of unmeasurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory

My understanding of the Vitali set construction boils it down to the creation of a set with the following properties:

1. The set S must have measure $0$
2. Countably infinite disjoint copies of S cover a set of finite positive measure

From this we get the great contradiction of the size of S simultaneously being non-zero to achieve the positive measure of the union, and being non-positive since any value summed infinitely is not finite. But this same conclusion should be reachable for any set satisfying these two criteria.

Begin with $I=[0,1]$, we construct $S_n$ by taking $n$ copies of $I$ and divide up the single interval in $n$ equal connected subintervals so that the $i^{th}$ copy of $I$, $I_i$ is the $i^{th}$ such interval. Hence, for example, let $n=5$, then $I_1=[0,\frac{1}{5})$, $I_2=[\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5})$, $I_3=[\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5})$, $I_4=[\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5})$, and $I_5=[\frac{4}{5},1]$.

Then, in each $I_i$, perform a Cantor set like action of removing the middle $\frac{1}{5}$ of each interval, but instead of deleting it, shift it onto $I_{i+1}$ with the removed interval from $I_n$ going to $I_1$. Then, perform the action again on each of the new smaller intervals found in each $I_i$, removing the middle $\frac{1}{5}$ and moving it to $I_{i+1}$.

If we perform this process infinitely, each $I_i$ set has become an infinitely spread out collection of points, but provably still has measure $\frac{1}{5}$ since each swapping of intervals preserves the measure, and are still bounded on $[0,1]$. Also, since they started disjoint, and each swap retains their disjointedness, the final limit sets will also be disjoint. When we union them, we will recover the original interval $[0,1]$ which has positive measure.

The next thing to be done is to show they are all congruent. From the cyclic nature of the interval swapping, the sets do have a symmetry to them, but since each $I_i$ starts at a different location on the cycle, they are not congruent. They can be replaced however with $n$ copies of the full cycle, essentially shifting all $n\phantom{2}I_i$'s so their starting intervals overlap, and then taking the union of those sets. This is the set $S_n$

This construction produces a set with measure (in this case) $\frac{9}{25}$, and 5 copies of it will disjointly cover the unit interval.

To take a smaller concrete example, look at the case for $n=2$ and denote by $I_i^k$, the $k^{th}$ application of the construction rule. Then $$I_1^0=[0,\frac{1}{2})$$ and $$I_2^0=[\frac{1}{2},1]$$ The construction would then have us remove the middle half of each interval and shift it to the other set. This is also the step where varying which subsets get shifted around and how yields so many different infinite families. This gives us $$I_1^1=[0,\frac{1}{8})\cup[\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{2})\cup [\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8})$$ $$I_2^1=[\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8})\cup[\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{8})\cup[\frac{7}{8},1]$$ Being the result of such a middle half shift operation. We can then apply the construction rule again to each of these intervals, removing it from the one and shifting it to the other.
$$I_1^2=[0,\frac{1}{32})\cup [\frac{3}{32},\frac{1}{8})\cup[\frac{5}{32},\frac{7}{32})\cup[\frac{3}{8},\frac{13}{32})\cup[\frac{15}{32},\frac{1}{2})\cup[\frac{17}{32},\frac{19}{32})\cup[\frac{5}{8},\frac{21}{32})\cup[\frac{23}{32},\frac{7}{8})\cup[\frac{29}{32},\frac{31}{32})$$

$$I_2^2=[\frac{1}{32},\frac{3}{32})[\frac{1}{8},\frac{5}{32})\cup[\frac{7}{32},\frac{3}{8})\cup[\frac{13}{32},\frac{15}{32})\cup[\frac{1}{2},\frac{17}{32})\cup[\frac{19}{32},\frac{5}{8})\cup[\frac{21}{32},\frac{23}{32})\cup[\frac{7}{8},\frac{29}{32})\cup[\frac{31}{32},1]$$ $$\vdots$$ As $k\rightarrow\infty$, these two sets will become dustlike clouds of points, but since all we did was shift one interval into the other's set, the total measure of their union is still $1$. To produce $S_2$ from this, we then need to reverse $I_2^{\infty}$ and overlap it with $I_1^{\infty}$ on their original intervals. This set will be vertically symmetric about its middle, will be bounded between $[-\frac{1}{2},1]$ and have measure $\frac{3}{4}$.

Now do the same process for $n=3,4,5,6,\dots$, and define $$S=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$$ Each $S_n$ has measure $\frac{2n-1}{n^2}$ since we can obtain the filled in version of the $I_i$'s by taking just $I_1$ and a shifted $I_n$, this gives us two sets of measure $\frac{1}{n}$, but their overlap removes $\frac{1}{n}$th of one of them, which has measure $\frac{1}{n^2}$. This shows that $$|S|=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|S_n|=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n-1}{n^2}=0$$ Thus, $S$ has measure $0$. Yet, since its construction is what it is, countably many disjoint copies of itself will cover $[0,1]$, which has positive measure.

The set S will also be bounded inside the interval $[-1,2]$ since the cycle of $I_n$'s can only shift over by (asymptotically) 1.

Hence, $S$ is a bounded set of measure $0$, yet countably infinite disjoint copies of it will cover a positive measure. Does this achieve an unmeasurable set? I feel like my construction is missing something basic about the relationships here. If this does work, then you can produce an arbitrarily large family of such sets by simply varying the way you remove and swap around the intervals.

Comment: We don't require $S$ to have $0$ measure, property $2$ is enough to show that $S$ isn't measurable. Your construction isn't clear, it seems you are defining some transformation of subset of $[0, 1]$, but what exactly and to what set you apply it - I can't understand. Also, if you have set with measure not equal to $1/5$ s.t. $5$ disjoint copies of it is $[0, 1]$, then you already have contradiction.

Comment: the 5 disjoint sets only cover [0,1] but extend both above and below it, so the union has at least measure 1, but not exactly. the construction is meant to break up [0,1] into n chunks separated into their own sets, the all n sets remove the middle nth of the interval, and add that removed interval to the next set in a cycle. doing ao infinitely results in a collection of sets with a fractal-like structure but which maintains a measure of 1/n.

Comment: Can you please write what sets you have on 1st and 2nd iteration? Because if you just exchange subintervals of parts of $[0, 1]$, then you get some bijection on $[0, 1]$, not a set.

Comment: @mihaild i have edited it accordingly

Comment: Are you sure you can define $I_1^\infty$? It seems that many points (probably all non dyadic rationals) appear in infinitely many $I_1^k$ and also in infinitely many $I_2^k$.

Comment: @mihaild this is the basis of my question. i know to prove $I_1^{\infty}$ exists i would need to demonstrate that the limit going across the entries, ie as $k\rightarrow\infty$, is the same as the limit going along an entry, ie as $n\rightarrow\infty$. this requires something like dominated convergence or something strong that i have little idea how to approach for this construction. its possible that herein lies my mistake in believing it even possible, but i dont know enough to confirm/refute it on my own.

Comment: I don't think I understand why we need $n \to \infty$ at this stage. You take $k \to \infty$ first to get $S_n$, is it so? But limit on sets is usually ill-defined, things like dominated convergence are about functions.

Comment: yes, as $k\rightarrow \infty$ we create the set $S_n$, but since n is fknite, then we need only finitely many copies of $S_n$ to cover [0,1]. to make the unmeasurable set, we need countably infinite copies to union to cover [0,1]. hence, we need to push $n\rightarrow\infty$. this way, the resulting $S_{\infty}=I_{\infty}^{\infty}$ will have the second criteria from above and hopefully is then unmeasurable

Comment: The problem I see is with definition of $I_1^\infty$ already (which is needed before talking about $S_n$). I understand what is $I_1^k$, but I don't understand how is $\lim_{k \to \infty} I_1^k$ defined. (I can also say that it's definitely impossible to build an unmeasurable set "constructively" - without using some amount of choice - but that definitely doesn't tell by itself where is the error in construction, just that there is one)

Comment: the axiom of choice logic you have is exactly what made me suspect it in the first place. if this works, then it would most likely be a huge even in measure theory so i doubt it works. i imagine the definition of $I_1^{\infty}$ is much like that of the Cantor set since it is a very similar process just generalized to moving subintervals around miltple numberlines rather than deleting them altogether. there it has an obvious base 3 characterization for its definition, but i suspect here it's either: therein lies the details where choice enters, or there we'll discover a contradiction.

Comment: Cantor set is defined as intersection of sets we get on each step - or, equal, we can say that next set we build is subset of the previous one. In such specific case limit of sets is well-defined. But, for example, can you even say if $1/3$ is in $I_1^\infty$, or not?

Comment: Re: axiom of choice - it would be the hugest event in the entire mathematics ever, because Solovay proved that if ZF is consistent then it has a model in which all sets are measurable - and so it's not possible to prove existence of non-measurable set in ZF.

Comment: due to the nature of the construction, all the $I_i$'s have the same endpoint to their intervals, simply if they are included or not is dependent on if that point appears as a left or a right endpoint in an interval. but once this endpoint is included in one of the $I_i$'s, its inclusion is preserved over all following iterations of the construction rule. this is to say, there are a countably infinite number of known points in $I_1^{\infty}$ since we can list each set of left endpoints at each iteration. now, whether or not $\frac{1}{3}\in I_1^{\infty}$ depends of the specific rule used

Comment: i suppose i would need to prove that the set of endpoints generated in the limit is dense, which sounds like that may be too challenging and might need choice

Comment: Yes, endpoints stabilise after appearance, but that's only dyadic rationals. But I think there are infinitely many $k$ s.t. $1/3 \in I_1^k$, and infinitely many $k$ s.t. $1/3 \not\in I_1^k$, so it's unclear how to check if $1/3 \in I_1^\infty$.

Comment: Doesn't that imply that $I_1^{\infty}$ should be dense around $\frac{1}{3}$? indeed any such number in the interior of all the intervals will just cycle membership through the $I_i$'s over and over. this means that each $I_i^{\infty}$ should possess members arbitrarily close to these strict interior points. i.e., even if $\frac{1}{3}\notin I_i^{\infty}$, we still have $\frac{1}{3}\in\overline{I_1^{\infty}}$, and similar for all such interior points. this isn't enough to establish measures or anything since $\mathbb{Q}$ is also dense. Is it this density problem where my construction fails?

Comment: You can't speak about $I_1^\infty$ until you define it - this is major problem I see, and we can't go further until it's solved (and also density isn't interesting property when we talk about measure - set can have zero measure and be everywhere dense, or positive measure and be nowhere dense).